# When run Visual Studio 2015 Crashed in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When i open Visual Studio 2015 Splash screen displayed and suddenly **"Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has Stopped Working"** message appear. I have tried to reinstall and repair the VS2015 but problem is still there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY9mX.jpg)

Comment: You should raise an issue with Microsoft.

Comment: I think its problem with windows updates or something like that. I have three Visual Studio (2005,2015,2017) installed on my machine. All providing same message on opening.